# jQuery mobile menu issue when re-sizing browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Okay, so I'm no jQuery expert (still learning) as I'm more of a front end guy.

First off, the site in question is http://dev.digitalskydesign.com

Go there in your desktop browser open to a normal size (at least 1000px wide).

You'll see the menu system works.

Now resize the browser to as narrow as it will go to simulate a mobile view. You'll see that the 'About' menu acts wonky when you click on it. It will open and then immediately close.

Now, refresh your browser (while still in mobile view) and you'll see the About menu works just fine.

So, what's happening is that when the site is resized on the fly, it's causing this weird issue.

You can see the jQuery code for the accordion menu function here:
http://dev.digitalskydesign.com/wp-content/plugins/accordion-menus/js/accordion-menus.js

Now I thought I had written this code correctly to take into consideration browser resizing by adding this snippet to the end of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// run test on initial page load
checkSize();

// run test on resize of the window
$(window).resize(checkSize);
});

//Function to the css rule
function checkSize(){
if ($("#nav-panel").css("position") == "fixed" ){
    accordion_menus();
}
}
```

It looks at the CSS media queries and determines if the #nav-panel container has a position of "fixed" (which only occurs on mobile sizes, at 768px wide or larger, it goes to "absolute"). If it does, it runs the accordion_menus function.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about it. The user using a mobile device do not need to resize the browser so the menu will work as expected. Keep in mind that the `media queries are loaded when the browser loads the site, and that  they are not aware about the fact that you are resizing the browser. I have just tried the site in my mobile deice and it is working correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's something I probably don't have to worry about, since no one will likely be resizing it in 'real-time' so to speak. I guess I'm just being OCD about the code is all :D